# How to remove a pattern using underscore.js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, underscore.js

i have a value like the following : `...India` in this i want to remove `...` if it is exist in the value.

How to do this using underscore.js or jquery or javascript ??

Thanks

Comment: `var myString = myString.replace('...,'');`

Comment: +1 for all the answers, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the basic JavaScript [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method

```
var myString = myString.replace('...','');
```

If you need more complex replacing then you will probably want to look into using a [RegEx pattern](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try regexp as:

```
"...India".replace(/\./g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

use `replace()`

```
var data="...India";
alert(data.replace('...',''));
```

however this replace all the occurence of the searched string... this won't work if you have just `..India` .